# Django Arrayfield of model vs ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models

Let's say I have 2 models, User and Book. User can have multiple books and book can belong to multiple users.
I only care to get what books each user has, and not so much about the other way around.

I am thinking about 2 solutions here: ManyToManyField and ArrayField of Book model.

What are the pros and cons? When I store ArrayField of Book model in User table, does Postgres duplicate the data in both Book and User table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use ArrayField or ManyToManyField for tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382653/should-i-use-arrayfield-or-manytomanyfield-for-tags)

Comment: This is different, that post is talking about tags which is just list of strings.

Comment: If you check the answers they are valid for your question too. Thus it seems like a duplicate.

Comment: What would be your ratio of queries for getting "books of a user" and "users of a book"?

Comment: books of a user will be much higher