# Which method is better for tagging in Django? ManyToMany or ArrayField?

Tags: django, database, optimization, query-optimization, django-orm

I'm building a new project in Django. This project contains `Users` and `Paintings`. One `User` owns many `Paintings`. And I want the `Users` to be able to tag their `Painting`, and later be able to sort them using the tags.

A `User` needs to be able to search by n tags at the same time. Also, the API will return tags compatible with their query. Say, for example, I have the following schema:

```json
{
  "User#1": {
    ...
    "paintings": {
      "Mona Lisa": {
        "tags": ["Da Vinci", "Gioconda", "Portrait", "Color"]
      },
      "Ginevra de' Benci": {
        "tags": ["Da Vinci", "Portrait", "Color"]
      },
      "The Last Supper": {
        "tags": ["Da Vinci", "Landscape", "Color"]
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Is the `User` wants to get all the `Paintings` with the tag "Portrait", the API will first return compatible tags ("Da Vinci", "Color", "Gioconda"), and then it'll return the `Paintings` with "Portrait" ("Mona Lista", "Ginevra de' Benci"). I want to offer the user an intuitive way to compose a long query of tags.

My question is: What's *better*? Using a "Tag" model and relate it to the `Painting` model with a ManyToMany? Or adding a "tags" ArrayField to the `Painting` model?

I'm asking about security, performance, and resource usage. I don't want any `User` to know what `Painting` the others have, but I don't want them to wait forever to get their query results. I also don't want to clog my database with excessively redundant data, but I need my users to be able to add (and create) new Tags on the fly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I use ArrayField or ManyToManyField for tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382653/should-i-use-arrayfield-or-manytomanyfield-for-tags)

Comment: Yeah, it works for my case. Thanks!