# Possible to create ArrayField for Django SQLite3 default DB?

Tags: django, django-models

I am working on my first Django project and right now I want the ability for the user to add multiple items to a model. It will look something like this in the admin panel.

```
Expected Values [______________] +
                [______________] 
                [______________]
```

Each time they click the "+" it will open another line for them to add anything.

From what I have came across so far is `ArrayField` is possibly what I want. However it seems that is not for the default Django DB SQLite3. I am trying to find a way to do what I want, while staying on SQLite3.

Is it worth staying on SQLite3?
Does switching to Postgres make what I want possible?

Thanks

Comment: The **`ArrayField`** is for the PostgreSQL database backend also the sqlite3 is not production friendly

Comment: So what you are saying is I should switch because the sqlite3 DB is more of a dev database?

Comment: Kind of, sqlite3 is development-friendly because it doesn't have to run a server.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will convert to PostgreSQL and use the ArrayField. Seems like the best choice.

Answer (score -1):

SQLite does not have `ArrayField` field type ([datatypes](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) docs), this field type is limited to PostgreSQL

You probably don't want to use `ArrayField` you want to use [database relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/)

Comment: I don't think that is what I need.

Comment: Yes you use ArrayField in very limited use case and this would not be it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27048400/django-postgres-arrayfield-vs-one-to-many-relationship

Comment: I am learning Django and I am not understanding how this would work. I guess I create a new model named "ExpectedValue". Give it a CharField. And then for each expected value it just creates a new ExpectedValue and assigns it to my model?

Comment: You can see it clearly here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Reporter can have many articles and yes something in line what you said

Comment: Also going through https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/ would be beneficiary for you