# how to input array in django html

Tags: python, html, django

I am new to django. I want to make a website to change tables in a database. It should be implemented change, deletion, addition of a note.
The problem is that one of the parameters of the Array table and I don't know how to make it input. I tried to do it through text input but it didn't work for me

Here is my code

**smj_prof must be array!**

**forms.py**

```
from .models import dj_ksg_p
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput

class KSGForms(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=dj_ksg_p
        fields=['id','name','c_prof','smj_prof','KSG']
        widgets={
            "id": TextInput(attrs={
                'class':'from-control',
                'placeholder':'Id'
            }),
            "name": TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'from-control',
                'placeholder': 'Название МО'
            }),
            "c_prof": TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'from-control',
                'placeholder': 'Профиль'
            }),
            "smj_prof": TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'from-control',
                'placeholder': 'Смежный профиль'#this should be array
            }),
            "KSG": TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'from-control',
                'placeholder': 'КСГ'
            })
        }
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic import DetailView, UpdateView,DeleteView
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import dj_ksg_p
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .forms import KSGForms
\#from .serializers import HeroSerializer

class KSGView(ListView):
model = dj_ksg_p
template_name = 'ksg/kss.html'
queryset = dj_ksg_p.objects.all()

class NewDataView(DetailView):
model = dj_ksg_p
template_name = 'ksg/create.html'
context_object_name = 'dj_ksg_p'

class DeleteKSG(DeleteView):
model = dj_ksg_p
template_name = 'ksg/delete.html'
success_url = '/ksg/'

class NewUpdateView(UpdateView):
model=dj_ksg_p
template_name = 'ksg/detail_view.html'
fields = \['id','name','c_prof','smj_prof','KSG'\]
form_class=dj_ksg_p

def create(request):
error = ''
if request.method =='POST':
form= KSGForms(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
form.save()
\#redirect()#Перенос
else:
error='Форма заполнения неверная'
form=KSGForms()
data={
'form':form,
'error':error
}
return render(request,'ksg/create.html',data)
```

**models.py**

```
from cleb import settings
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import Error
from django.db import connection
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class dj_ksg_p(models.Model):
    id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, serialize=True, unique=True)
    name=models.TextField()
    c_prof=models.IntegerField()
    smj_prof=ArrayField(
        models.IntegerField()
    )
    KSG=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    #def __str__(self):
        #return self.s
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f'ksg/{self.id}'
    class Meta:
        db_table='ksg_p'
```

**kss.html**

```
{% load static%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'ksg/css/ksg.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<table>
     <colgroup>
         <col span="2" style="background:Khaki"><!-- С помощью этой конструкции задаем цвет фона для первых двух столбцов таблицы-->
         <col style="background-color:LightCyan"><!-- Задаем цвет фона для следующего (одного) столбца таблицы-->
         <col style="background-color:Khaki">
     </colgroup>
    <!--   <tbody>-->
 <caption>Профили</caption>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>C_PROF</th>
    <th>smj_prof</th>
    <th>KSG</th>
</tr>
{% for serv in object_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ serv.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ serv.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ serv.c_prof }} </td>
        <td>{{ serv.smj_prof}}</td>
        <td>{{ serv.KSG }}</td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'create' %}"><button class="btn btn-info">Добавить запись</button></a></td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'ksg_detail' serv.id %}" class="btn btn-warning">Изменить</a></td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'ksg_delete' serv.id %}" class="btn btn-info">Удалить</a></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
<!-- ><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"> </tbody>-->
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**create.html**

```
{% load static%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'ksg/css/ksg.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="features">
    <h1>Форма добавления записи</h1>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}<br>
        {{form.id}}<br>
        {{form.name}}<br>
        {{form.c_prof}}<br>
        {{form.smj_prof}<br>
        {{form.KSG}}<br>
        <span>{{error}}</span>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Добавить статью</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here how my site looks
[table with buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGa1T.png)
[add/update column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uItWW.png)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to mention "action" in "form" tag, which decides the view that needs to be executed. Below is an example of form submitting in django using function based views, follow the approach, please don't copy the code.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it dont answe my question. I am already succesfuly can connect obtain table via from. My problem is i cant enter array. I tried to it with action it still the same

Comment: If you are using "sqllite", it is recommended to make use of relationships to fullfill your requirement. If you are using "postgresql", it has arrayfield that can be used directly. 
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27048400/django-postgres-arrayfield-vs-one-to-many-relationship